# Get filename without path in Spark DataFrame SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark Dataframe, which has data from a parsed XML folder through spark-xml. I want to add a column containing the source file, which is easily done through the input_file_name() function.

The problem is that this returns the whole path, and I want only the filename. So I tried registering a UDF in spark SQL, which extracts the filename, but I get an empty columns in the end. The function works, but apparently it gets empty values as an input, and I don't understand why.

Does anyone know this issue and how to solve it?

EDIT: Example

If I select the filename column through `df.selectExpr('input_file_name()')` then I get the path and filename. If I however define a function simply returning the input:

```
def f(path):
    return path
```

and register it through `session.udf.register('f',f)`, and select the column again through `df.selectExpr('f(input_file_name())')`, I get an empty column.

Comment: can you please provide reproducible code to illustrate your question?

Comment: added an example. thanks.

Comment: @stackoverflowthebest: did you try `df.select()` instead of `df.selectExpr()`?

Comment: it doesn't work at all with that, not even directly calling `df.select('input_file_name()')`. I need the function to be registered as a sql function, not externally. If I call e.g. `df.selectExpr('f(anyothercolumn)')` it works normally with other columns from the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

We can register an `udf` that will return only the part of the string after the last `"/"`, and apply this function to the output of `input_file_name()`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name

spark.udf.register("filename", lambda x: x.rsplit('/', 1)[-1])
df.selectExpr('filename(input_file_name()) as file')
```

Comment: As I wrote earlier, I need to register the function as a SQL function, so that I can call it inside a query, and not externally as your example. It should work since all other functions work, with other columns, this is the only one not working.

Comment: Yes, it is, but I already have the function. The problem is that it returns an empty column. Doesn't matter how you define the function, because the input (x in your example), is already empty when it enters the function, and I don't understand why, because if I use another column instead of input_file_name(), it works.

Comment: Really? That's weird. Did you also use spark-xml to read an XML file? I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: I load the data with spark-xml. The weird thing is that the filename column is working, but doesn't get passed to the udf.